# Run a process every alternate x hours

Tags: python, linux, unix

I have a python script which I am running like this as shown below:

```
python3 ./bin/abc.py --log_file ./web/prr.log
```

Now I need to make sure that above process runs after every 3 hours. Below is the flow:

- If the process is running already, then kill the process and sleep for 3 hours.
- After sleeping for 3 hours, if process is not running, start the process again by executing above python command and then sleep for three hours.
- Repeat the above process.

So meaning, I need to make sure that my process is running every alternate 3 hours so I need to find a way to kill the process after every 3 hours. I was thinking to use `watch` command here but not sure how can I use it here. I am working with Ubuntu 14.

**Note:** I can't modify the python script so I need to do it from outside of it.

Comment: You've done a good job of describing the steps needed.  Each of the pieces is a well-documented technique.  Where are you stuck?  There's no question in all of this.

Comment: I am stuck in using `watch` command here.I know I can use watch command here but not sure how can I formulate all the above steps in that single watch command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an ideal use case for [crontab](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference). I'd write 2 bash scripts that run every 3 hours via cron. So something like the following:

```
#ScriptA.sh
ifProcessRunning
    KillProcess

#ScriptB.sh
ifProcessNotRunning
    StartProcess

#CronTab
0,6,12,18 * * * * ScriptA.sh
3,9,15,21 * * * * ScriptB.sh
```

For killing the process you can use any normal unix command, so piping a `ps aux` and running kill within the shell script could work.

Hopefully this helps -- comment if you want me to flesh things out more!

Comment: I am sure it can be done in a single script or command I believe.

Comment: Okay -- perhaps you should edit your original question then with all required parameters. Are you dead set on using watch? Is this a homework assignment? What other parameters are there?

Comment: This doesn't quite do the job.  If the process finishes on its own within the 3-hour period, then you need to start another one right away, not wait for the next 6n+3 boundary.

Comment: No I am not dead set on using `watch`. I was reading about it how we can do this sort of thing and I saw there is a watch command but coudln't make it work. So I am open to any thing which can make this work. And no it's not an homework assignment.

Comment: @Prune the question seems ambiguous to me. The asker states that we need to A) kill the process and sleep for three hours B) start the process and sleep for three hours. It doesn't ever say that it needs to be running constantly. Was that your intention @user1950349? Can you clarify?

Comment: If I'm interpreting your problem correctly, it's easy enough to alter this solution: `if ProcessRunning then kill process; else start process`.  Set that one script  to run every 3 hours.

Comment: @PeterDolan yes it needs to run constantly every alternate 3 hours.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a single bash script to get check if the python script is running. If it is, it will kill the script. If not, it will start the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep -f <program name> > /dev/null
    then
         echo "Process is running. Killing"
         kill -9 $(pidof <program name>)
    else
         echo "Process is not running. Starting"
         python <location of the file>
    fi
```