# How to make this script loop every hour

Tags: python, html, loops, web, twitter

I'm creating a bot that posts every 60 minutes covid numbers, I have it finished but idk how to make it repeat. Any idea? It's a little project that I have in mind and it's the last thing I have to do. (if you answer the code from the publication with inside the solution it would be very cool)

```
import sys
CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXX'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'XXXX'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'XXXX'
import tweepy

import requests
from lxml import html


def create_tweet():
    response = requests.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/')
    doc = html.fromstring(response.content)
    total, deaths, recovered = doc.xpath('//div[@class="maincounter-number"]/span/text()')

    tweet = f'''Coronavirus Latest Updates
Total cases: {total}
Recovered: {recovered}
Deaths: {deaths}

Source: https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

#coronavirus #covid19 #coronavirusnews #coronavirusupdates #COVID19
'''
    return tweet


if __name__ == '__main__':
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

    # Create API object
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    try:
        api.verify_credentials()
        print('Authentication Successful')
    except:
        print('Error while authenticating API')
        sys.exit(5)

    tweet = create_tweet()
    api.update_status(tweet)
    print('Tweet successful')
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424885/run-a-process-every-alternate-x-hours help?

Comment: Which operating system? Whichever type, it will have a way to schedule periodic execution.

Comment: i use windows 10

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add this statement at the end of the code

```
sleep(3600)
```

If you want it to run endlessly, you can do it like this:

```
while True:
    insert your main code here
    sleep(3600)
```

Comment: idk why it crashes when i add it like u said.

Comment: Oh yes, you have to import the time library. `from time import *` Or just `from time import sleep`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a timer like this one below.
(The function refresh refers to itself every hour)

```py
from threading import Timer

def refresh(delay_repeat=3600): # 3600 sec for one hour
    # Your refresh script here
    # ....
    # timer
    Timer(delay_repeat, refresh, (delay_repeat, )).start()
```

Have a look at my runnable refresh graph here to have an idea :
[How can I dynamically update my matplotlib figure as the data file changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406385/how-can-i-dynamically-update-my-matplotlib-figure-as-the-data-file-changes/61711329#61711329)

Comment: idk why it crashes when i add it like u said.

Comment: do you have GUI in your app ? you should take a refresh action on GUI by posting an event not force the refresh

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a scheduler, there is already a built-in one in Python (`sched`), read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the task scheduler in Python. "schedule" is a library in python which you can install using pip or conda. This Library allows you rerun a function after a given interval (daily, hourly weekly etc).

First you need to install the library using pip

```
pip install schedule
```

Secondly, Put your code in a function. For e.g:

```
def theCode():
    print("Do Something")
```

Third, set the schedule:

```
schedule.every(2).hours.do(theCode)
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(10)
```